# Implementing a range in HTML time input

Tags: html, validation, text, input, time

I have been asked to help fix a bug in a web application that is mostly python (running Flask) which is what I know and why I offered to help. However my HTML knowledge is very bad and I need help. I've fixed the bug in the python code, but I want to make sure the user can't find more ways to break the application. It has to do with the form in HTML where users input the time for a deal. The input is in text format with the placeholder 'hh:mm:ss' but that doesn't stop them from entering all kinds of things other than a time in that format. If I had done this from the beginning I would have made this field a 'time' format but too many things depend on it being a text field now that I would rather just set some validation on this text input field.

The piece of code is:

```
<input type="text" name="time_left" id="time_left" placeholder="hh:mm:ss">
```

The only restriction is that the time can't be less than 00:00:00 and it can't be more than 01:30:00. I would love to just put a min/max attribute in here somewhere but I doubt it's that simple. Especially with it being text.

Can anyone advise me what I can do (the simpler the better, as I say, I'm not very good with HTML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTML5 only solutions, there are two ways. One is to make it a `type="time"` input. It's value can still be read with `input.value` as a string, if that's of any concern to you.

```
<input type="time" min="00:00:00" max="01:30:00">
```

Browsers will allow [steps of 1 minute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#time-state-(type=time):attr-input-step). If you need second precision, add a `step="1"`.

The other solution is to add the `pattern` attribute:

```
<input type="text" pattern="0(1:30:00|1:[012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|0:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])">
```

Both solutions are viable and each has its advantages and disadvantages.

The latter will have better browser support, but for support closer to 100% you will either way need a JS library that takes over from the browser. I wrote [Hyperform](https://hyperform.js.org), that would do that (and more), but if it's just this one field you might be better off writing your own event handler and attaching it to the `change` event of that input field.

*Edit:* The regexp in the `pattern` attribute will distinguish several cases separated by `|`. The first and simplest is the max time `01:30:00`. The next are the times from 01:00 to 01:29:59, and finally the times from 00:00 to 00:59:59.

Comment: I used the second option and it did what I was looking for. Thank you! I am now just adding a description on the page to let users know this is the range they're allowed.
Not urgent but is there a way to make the leading 0 optional? like:
<input type="text" pattern="0?(1:30:00|1:[012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|0:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])">
... or something

Comment: Yes, the `0?` should work just fine. The content of the `pattern` attribute is basically a regexp as understood by Javascript, with implicit starting `^` and ending `$`.

Comment: Cool, is there any way to change the message from "Please match the requested format" to something more specific (instead of adding a description on the page)

Comment: Add a `title` attribute. That will be used as part of the error message: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-title